# TypeError: find_element() got multiple values for argument 'by'

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to scrape linkedin using selenium, but while trying to select the username element, the command doesn't seen to work, can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Code I'm using:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\capta\Documents\chromedriver - Chrome 112\\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get ("https://linkedin.com/uas/login")

time.sleep(5)

username = driver.find_element("username", by=By.ID)

time.sleep(3)

username.send_keys("username")
```

Error message is in title. by=By.ID is after the string to resolve another error telling me it had to be in that order, even though the tooltip tells me to put it in the reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax in the below line of code is incorrect:

```
username = driver.find_element("username", by=By.ID)
```

It should be:

```
username = driver.find_element(By.ID, "username")
```

Comment: Share that syntax error in your question.